# Python - Saving individual frames of animation

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

I have an animation in Python, a FuncAnimation object, which is updating every 1 minute. I can save each frame of this animation, for example as 'animationframe.png', but the save function always adds a '-1' or '-2', etc to the end of the file name. For example:

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib import animation

...code defining animate, etc. ...
fig = plt.figure()
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=sleepTime)

... stuff to add a title, labels to plot ...

anim.save('animationframe.png')
plt.show()
```

When I run the program, I get the frames in files named: 
animationframe-0.png
animationframe-1.png
animationframe-2.png
animationframe-3.png
animationframe-4.png
...

However, I only want the frames to be saved to one file, animationframe.png, since I'm displaying that file on an HTML file that updates every minute.

Is there any way to save each frame of the animation in the same file, just overwriting each time or deleting the existing file and saving a new file?

Unless there's a way to have Python output this animation onto an HTML file?

Thanks!